# How can I perform linear regression on a file geodatabase table in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, regression

I'm trying to use the Ordinary Least Squares tool in ArcGIS 10.2 but it only accepts feature classes as input and I have a file geodatabase table. I realize that I can export the table to Excel or MATLAB and perform the linear regression there, but I am working in ModelBuilder and need to keep everything within the model. Are there any workarounds or conversions that anyone knows about?

Comment: Is it possible to create a shapefile based on your table then use the OLS tool on the shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a script tool via Python?

I use the scipy Python module...

scipy.stats.linregress()

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Installing scipy on the top of the ArcGIS Python install is not very straightforward, so beware...

Comment: Good idea.  I believe `scipy` is included with the arcgis install of Python.

Comment: Clarification: scipy libabry is NOT included with the arcgis install of Python (at least not at 10.2.2).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I forgot that I had installed `scipy` at an earlier occasion.

Comment: Cool, I think scipy is going to be the way to go. Now I just have to figure out how to configure the script tool to take columns from my table as parameters.